# Centrifugal compressor calculation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, centrifugal-force

I'm trying to get a rough idea of the different variables in an air centrifugal compressor (especially the RPM of the impeller).

Being more specific, is there a way to roughly estimate the RPM of the impeller if the diameter of the compressor and the input and output pressures are given?

For example, if I want to compress 100 liters/min of air to 7 bar from atmospheric pressure, how big would be the compressor, and how fast the impeller needs to turn?

I know that there are many variables involved, but just I'm just looking for a rough idea.

Comment: You can start here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfRurnxM3m4, but at the end of your search, you should talk to a manufacturer for specific details.  One such manufacturer is Ingersoll Rand.